# How to use function within class for ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've created a WordPress plugin for my custom Stripe Checkout integration.

I'm extending a WooCommerce class which then has the ajax initialisers and functions:

```
class WC_Stripe_Checkout_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

  public function __construct() {

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'payment_scripts' ) );

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_create_checkout_session', array( $this, 'create_checkout_session' ) ); 
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_create_checkout_session', array( $this, 'create_checkout_session' ) );

  }

}
```

```
public function payment_scripts() {

   // Load relevant JS on checkout page only.
   if( is_checkout() ) {

     // Enqueue Stripe JS
     wp_enqueue_script( 'stripe_js', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/' );

     // and this is our custom JS in your plugin directory that works with token.js
     wp_register_script( 'stripecheckout_js', plugins_url( '../scripts/stripe_checkout.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );

     wp_enqueue_script( 'stripecheckout_js' );

     // 
     wp_localize_script( 'stripecheckout_js', 'stripejs_ajax', array(
      // 'publishableKey' => $this->publishable_key
      'url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'stripe_checkout_session_nonce' ),
     ) );

   }

  }
```

I should be able to make an ajax request to `create_checkout_session` but I receive an error 400 in the console.

```
jQuery( function($) {     
  $("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function() {
    
    $.ajax({
      url: stripejs_ajax.url,
      data: {
        action: 'create_checkout_session',
        nonce: stripejs_ajax.nonce
      }
    })
    .done( function(response) {
      if(response.type == 'success') {
        console.log('level 1');
      }
      else {
        console.log('level 2');
      }
    })
    .fail( function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  
  });

});
```

**Error**:

```
https://example.test/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=create_checkout_session&nonce=5c6cf91687 400
```

Is it correct to have the function I want to ajax call within the class which then extends `WC_Payment_Gateway`, could this be causing any issues?

Comment: Have you registered your payment class with `woocommerce_payment_gateways` filter?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka - do I need to if I am already doing `extends WC_Payment_Gateway`?

Comment: By extending you just inherit properties of a parent class, but not registering your custom class itself. So WordPress doesn't know about your class.

Comment: Ah ok. Added `new WC_Stripe_Checkout_Gateway();` to the bottom of the file, seems to be working finally! Although would like to confirm that's the most suitable method?

Comment: Does it shows as an available payment method inside admin-panel?

Comment: Yep, it did before too. Although my ajax wasn't working until I added `new WC_Stripe_Checkout_Gateway();`

Comment: I just checked, inside `init` method of a `WC_Payment_Gateway` it just creates new instances of any payment gateways. So it is ok